# In how many ways we can create a PS file in Mainframes?

Tags: cobol, jcl

How many ways we can create A PS file using jcl.**strong text**

Answer (score 2):

z/OS supports a couple of different *data set organizations*, short DSORGs. Data set organizations are

- Physical Sequential, DSORG=PS
- Partitioned Organized, DSORG=PO. There are two subtypes: PDS and PDS/E
- Direct Access, DSORG=DA
- Virtual Storage Access Method (the name *is* irritating, it is a DISK data set), DSORG=VS. There are a couple of subtypes.

The creation of a new data set is called *allocation*. Allocation is finally performed by calling internal system services. That means, you can code an assembler of C program to offer the allocation of a new data set. Therefore, the number of ways is unlimited.

However, the following ways are offered by z/OS, so you don't need to write a program on your own.

**1. JCL**

You can allocate a new PS, PO, or DA data set with JCL keywords on a `DD` statement. The main indicator that you want to allocate a *new* data set is `DISP=(NEW,...)`. (Any other `DISP=` option allocates an existing data set.) The keyword `DSORG=` determines the type of data set. If it is omitted, the keyword `SPACE=` determines whether a PS or a PDS is allocated. If `SPACE=`specifies *primary*, *secondary*, **and** *directory* space amounts, a PDS is allocated, else a PS.

With limitations, you can also allocate a new VSAM data set with JCL keywords.

**2. TSO/E**

You can use the TSO/E `ALLOC` command to do (almost) the same as with JCL `DD` statement keywords (see above). Again, the keyword `DISP(NEW,...)` is used to allocate a *new* data set.

**3. ISPF**

You can use ISPF panels in a TSO/E session to allocate a new data sets.

**4. Program IDCAMS**

You can run program `IDCAMS` in a batch job to allocate a new data set. This is the preferred method to allocate VSAM data sets.

**Other**

There are possibilites, depending on the tools that are available at your installation.

**Note** that *members* of PDS, and PDS/E data sets are **not* allocated. Once a PDS, or PDS/E has been allocated, members can be created. But we do not say "allocate a member". A new allocation is tied to reserving some disk space for he data set. Members make use of that space.

There is more behind *allocation*; too much to write it all down here.